# Bash file existence checking missing ]

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting a simple file existence check in my bash script:

```
FILE_TO_CHECK=/home/username/path/to/file

if [ ! -f $FILE_TO_CHECK]; #line 9 in actual script
then
    echo File not found.
fi
```

Seems simple enough to me, but I'm getting the following error and I don't know why:

```
/path/to/script: line 9: [: missing `]'
```

I'm not exactly a bash expert, but I was pretty sure a backtick is not necessary in this context. What gives?

Comment: Typo: Add space before `]`

Comment: Also, since you're using `[ ... ]` rather than `[[ ... ]]`, it is generally safer to double-quote `$FILE_TO_CHECK`. Re backtick: the error message is not telling you to use a backtick, it (strangely) uses a backtick instead of a single quote for what should be a `]` in single quotes.

Comment: Dear moderators, the question itself was upvoted twice. Unlikely to help future readers?! Let me inform you, it is extremely helpful to understand what are [ and ] in shell scripts, and why spaces around them are crucial. It is definitely not a simple typographical error.

Comment: As the original poster, I feel it's necessary to clarify that this was not a typo. I had no idea that [ and ] needed to be separated by spaces, and could not find the answer after extensive Google searching. I think it's conceivable a future reader might run into the same problem. Additionally, the replies I've received taught me a great deal about the mechanics of bash scripting - both in the script itself and the error message I received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing space before the closing `]`.

You have to understand that `[` is a command and everything following it, until the `;`, are its arguments.  Command `[` expects its last argument to be `]`. But if you omit the space, then `]` becomes the last character of the previous argument.

It might seem that `[ ]` is part of the `if` syntax. It's not the case. `if` has to be followed by any command, and `if` evaluates its exit status.

```
if true; then foo; fi
```

In the above line `true` is a command too.

```
$ which true
/bin/true
```

`true` is a command with the sole purpose of always having a true (0) exit status.

Comment: Womp womp. That was it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
if (test ! -f $FILE_TO_CHECK);
```

or

```
if !(test -f $FILE_TO_CHECK);
```

as `[` is a shorthand for the `test` command.